# How can I add a ColorChanged event to ColorDialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, colordialog

I want to process an event at point when the user chooses a color.
Is it possible to add ColorChanged event to the ColorDialog?

Comment: Color dialog is a piece of cr*p; doesn't even support Alpha. Write your own of find one on the Web! Then you can add an event or delegate to it, I assume for showing a preview?

Comment: Yes, for show a preview. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean before you've pressed `OK`, then the answer is most likely no.

The `ColorDialog` is just a wrapper for a native Win32 dialog, and it's very hard (maybe even impossible) to modify them from .NET.

I'd say your best option is to create a form mimicking the dialog's layout, and implement the event there.

Comment: There is no any message for that?

Comment: @user6466445 : Not that I am aware of. But even if there were, you would still have to capture it _from the dialog_ as it **won't** be sent to any of your forms.